# Storing composite/nested object graph

Tags: c#, bson, mongodb-.net-driver

I am currently developing a document store in Mongo DB which contains a complete material breakdown of a specific item. The breakdown is calculated and contains a composite structure.

The domain model:

```
public interface IReagent
{
    int ItemId { get; set; }
    int Quantity { get; set; }
    ConcurrentBag<IReagent> Reagents { get; set; }
}

public class Craft : IReagent
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int SpellId { get; set; }
    public int Skill { get; set; }
    public Profession Profession { get; set; }
    public ConcurrentBag<IReagent> Reagents { get; set; }
}

public class Reagent : IReagent
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public ConcurrentBag<IReagent> Reagents { get; set; }
}
```

Now the problem is that a composite structure is not correctly stored. Reagents stays null in mongodb.

```
/* 28 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4e497efa97e8b617f0d229d4"),
  "ItemId" : 52186,
  "Quantity" : 0,
  "SpellId" : 0,
  "Skill" : 475,
  "Profession" : 8,
  "Reagents" : { }
}
```

**Example of how it should look**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4e497efa97e8b617f0d229d4"),
    "ItemId" : 52186,
    "Quantity" : 0,
    "SpellId" : 0,
    "Skill" : 475,
    "Profession" : 8,
    "Reagents" : [
        {
            "ItemId" : 521833,
            "Quantity" : 3,
            "SpellId" : 0,
            "Skill" : 400,
            "Profession" : 7,
            "Reagents" : [
                {
                    "ItemId" : 52186,
                    "Quantity" : 3,
                    "SpellId" : 0,
                    "Skill" : 475,
                    "Profession" : 8,
                    "Reagents" : [
                        {
                            "ItemId" : 52183,
                            "Quantity" : 2,
                            "Reagents" : []
                        },
                        {
                            "ItemId" : 521832,
                            "Quantity" : 1,
                            "Reagents" : []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "ItemId" : 52386,
                    "Quantity" : 2
                    "SpellId" : 0,
                    "Skill" : 400,
                    "Profession" : 8,
                    "Reagents" : [
                        {
                            "ItemId" : 52383,
                            "Quantity" : 2,
                            "Reagents" : []
                        },
                        {
                            "ItemId" : 523832,
                            "Quantity" : 1,
                            "Reagents" : []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: I assume it is non-null when passed in? Can I check - do you really need `ConcurrentBag<T>` here? would `List<T>` not suffice? you might find it happier w/ that? Note that I also wonder if `IReagant` being an interface is the fundamental problem, as unless it stores type info (i.e. the concrete reagant type) it can't know what to reconstruct

Comment: When I check "crafts" in runtime debugging it contains a composite structure. I am using the Parallel .NET 4.0 lib of MS to compute the object graph so a ConcurrentBag is needed to avoid using locks. I was already suspecting something like this. That it wouldn't support interfaces, though Craft is also a implementing IReagent and gets stored.

Comment: Storing an instance of `Craft` is different to storing an instance of `IReagant` that *happens to be* a `Craft`. Especially to serialization libraries (trust me on this ;p)

Comment: I believe you :D Just was wondering why the serializer recognizes Craft and not a IEnumerable<IReagent>. It is basically a list mixed with a concrete instances of either Craft or Reagent. The BSON serializer is not that intelligent I guess. I also did some tests with Redis (and the redis driver, in that case it just worked). I guess adding a custom serializer (as posted below) would solve the issue :)

Comment: because in the case of `Craft` it *knows the type* - it is `Craft`. Now: what object do you create for an `IReagant`?

Comment: The list either contains a instances of Craft or Reagent. The Reagents can also be null deeper down in the craft. If Reagents is null its a Reagent. I've added an example of how it should look as BSON, hopefully it clarifies that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are using list of abstractions and it cannot serialize these to JSON, so basically you would need to write your own custom serialization. Here is example of custom serialization I wrote:

```
 public class FieldsWrapper : IBsonSerializable
    {
        public List<DataFieldValue> DataFieldValues { get; set; }


        public object Deserialize(MongoDB.Bson.IO.BsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
        {
        if (nominalType != typeof(FieldsWrapper)) throw new ArgumentException("Cannot deserialize anything but self");
        var doc = BsonDocument.ReadFrom(bsonReader);
        var list = new List<DataFieldValue>();
        foreach (var name in doc.Names)
        {
            var val = doc[name];
            if (val.IsString)
                list.Add(new DataFieldValue {LocalIdentifier = name, Values = new List<string> {val.AsString}});
            else if (val.IsBsonArray)
            {
                DataFieldValue df = new DataFieldValue {LocalIdentifier = name};
                foreach (var elem in val.AsBsonArray)
                {
                    df.Values.Add(elem.AsString);
                }
                list.Add(df);
            }
        }
        return new FieldsWrapper {DataFieldValues = list};
        }


        public void Serialize(MongoDB.Bson.IO.BsonWriter bsonWriter, Type nominalType, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
        {
            if (nominalType != typeof (FieldsWrapper))
                throw new ArgumentException("Cannot serialize anything but self");
            bsonWriter.WriteStartDocument();
            foreach (var dataFieldValue in DataFieldValues)
            {

                bsonWriter.WriteName(dataFieldValue.LocalIdentifier);
                if (dataFieldValue.Values.Count != 1)
                {
                    var list = new string[dataFieldValue.Values.Count];
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataFieldValue.Values.Count; i++)
                        list[i] = dataFieldValue.Values[i];
                    BsonSerializer.Serialize(bsonWriter, list); 
                }
                else
                {
                    BsonSerializer.Serialize(bsonWriter, dataFieldValue.Values[0]); 
                }
            }
            bsonWriter.WriteEndDocument();
        }

    }
```

In your case I would write my custom serialization on the level of Reagent class

Comment: Thanks for posting, defenitly gonna try this out tonight :)

Answer (score 0):

Implenting IBsonSerializer worked :) Did a quick mock up and it worked pretty well :D I got another suggestion from someone who says a `List<T>` would work, gonna try that later this week. And post the results here.

```
/* 3131 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4e4d58df77d2cf00691aaef2"),
  "ItemId" : 28432,
  "Quantity" : 0,
  "Reagents" : [{
      "ItemId" : 23448,
      "Quantity" : 0,
      "Reagents" : [{
          "ItemId" : 23447,
          "Quantity" : 0,
          "Reagents" : [{
              "ItemId" : 23427,
              "Quantity" : 2,
              "Reagents" : []
            }]
        }, {
          "ItemId" : 23445,
          "Quantity" : 0,
          "Reagents" : [{
              "ItemId" : 23424,
              "Quantity" : 2,
              "Reagents" : []
            }]
        }]
    }, {
      "ItemId" : 23572,
      "Quantity" : 8,
      "Reagents" : []
    }, {
      "ItemId" : 28431,
      "Quantity" : 0,
      "Reagents" : [{
          "ItemId" : 23571,
          "Quantity" : 0,
          "Reagents" : [{
              "ItemId" : 21885,
              "Quantity" : 1,
              "Reagents" : []
            }, {
              "ItemId" : 21884,
              "Quantity" : 1,
              "Reagents" : []
            }, {
              "ItemId" : 22451,
              "Quantity" : 0,
              "Reagents" : [{
                  "ItemId" : 21885,
                  "Quantity" : 1,
                  "Reagents" : []
                }]
            }, {
              "ItemId" : 22452,
              "Quantity" : 1,
              "Reagents" : []
            }, {
              "ItemId" : 22457,
              "Quantity" : 0,
              "Reagents" : [{
                  "ItemId" : 21884,
                  "Quantity" : 1,
                  "Reagents" : []
                }]
            }]
        }, {
          "ItemId" : 22456,
          "Quantity" : 0,
          "Reagents" : [{
              "ItemId" : 21885,
              "Quantity" : 1,
              "Reagents" : []
            }]
        }, {
          "ItemId" : 23573,
          "Quantity" : 0,
          "Reagents" : [{
              "ItemId" : 23446,
              "Quantity" : 0,
              "Reagents" : [{
                  "ItemId" : 23425,
                  "Quantity" : 2,
                  "Reagents" : []
                }]
            }]
        }, {
          "ItemId" : 23448,
          "Quantity" : 0,
          "Reagents" : [{
              "ItemId" : 23447,
              "Quantity" : 0,
              "Reagents" : [{
                  "ItemId" : 23427,
                  "Quantity" : 2,
                  "Reagents" : []
                }]
            }, {
              "ItemId" : 23445,
              "Quantity" : 0,
              "Reagents" : [{
                  "ItemId" : 23424,
                  "Quantity" : 2,
                  "Reagents" : []
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

**Serialization impl:**

```
public void Serialize(MongoDB.Bson.IO.BsonWriter bsonWriter, Type nominalType, MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializationOptions options)
{
    if (nominalType != typeof(IReagent) && nominalType != typeof(Reagent) && nominalType != typeof(Craft))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Cannot serialize anything but self");
    }

    bsonWriter.WriteStartDocument();

    bsonWriter.WriteInt32("ItemId", this.ItemId);
    bsonWriter.WriteInt32("Quantity", this.Quantity);

    if (this.Reagents != null)
    {
        bsonWriter.WriteName("Reagents");
        bsonWriter.WriteStartArray();

        foreach (var r in this.Reagents)
        {
            BsonSerializer.Serialize(bsonWriter, r.GetType(), r, options);
        }

        bsonWriter.WriteEndArray();
    }

    bsonWriter.WriteEndDocument();

}
```